# Create a new table vs modify existing table in DB

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle11g

The question may sound vague , but am in a situation where I have to decide between the two options.

Say we have multiple requirements(modules) which require some configuration.
Is it preferable to have one configuration table per module or maintain single table for all the configurations.

Driver (or attributes) for the configuration for individual requirement might be different , so in case am opting for a single table, I will have to make sure driver of individual requirements is available or maintained in this single table. also, we may have to  extend it in in case we have some more driver column in future requirements

Note : Data to be configured per module wont be more than 20 rows.

I have to analyse this and am just listing the pros and cons of this.

Please advise.

Also is there any disadvantage of having so many tables with this less data from DB point of view..

Comment: Use one single table for all the configurations. Much easier to maintain when new configurations are added (or removed.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, that made me edit the description itself. Please advice  if we should still go for single table and if so why ?? thanks again

Comment: @Anshoo: This sounds like a typical case for a key-value table (section, key, value): ('Module 1', 'FULL_SCREEN', 'YES'), ('Module 2', 'NEEDS_LOGIN', 'NO'), ... But maybe your situation is different. Would you somehow benefit from separate tables with specific attributes?

Comment: In this case ( configuration data => similar data, only few changes and only few data), you could alternatively think of storing it into a single table but using xmltype datatype.

Comment: @Thorsten, thanks. Yes the key value table is one thing I want to go for but i have to persuade the team why we should go for this approach instead of individual table per module

Comment: A key-value table is easy to maintain. New attribute = new entry in the table. New module = new entry in the table. No database changes needed. The argument against it could be typos: 'FULL_SCREAN', 'YESS', ...).

Comment: It also depends how you retrieve and use the data. Is it queried once per view, then a single table would make it faster. Is is cached in the front-end, then doing a more "proper" normalization would perhaps be worth it in the long run. Personally I would probably choose to separate the data as much as possible. The requirements always seem to change, and making room for these changes now will pay off in the long run. I'm not talking about one table per module here, that's not a good option in any scenario. But one table to keep the modules, one for the keys, etc.

Comment: thankyou all. I assume this depends more of the scenarios. I will also go with a single table to cater configurations to an extent